# Python visual module generates error message

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to python and i'm working thru some examples in a book. Several test cases use the 'visual' module. The visual package has been loaded on my iMac with OSX 10.13 using pip. The simple code I'm running is:

```
from visual.graph import *
funct1 = gcurve(color = color.cyan)

for x in arange(0.0, 8.1, 0.1):
    funct1.plot(pos = (x, 5.0*cos(2*x)*exp(-0.4*x)))

graph1 = gdisplay(x=0, y=0, width=600, height=450,
         title='Visual',xtitle='x', ytitle = ' f(x)',
         xmax = 5., xmin =-6., ymax=1, ymin = -1.5,
         foreground=color.black, background=color.white)

plotObj = gdots(color=color.black)

for x in arange(-5., 5., 0.1):
    plotObj.plot(pos = (x, cos(x)))`
```

The line 'from visual.graph import *' generates the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/johnhanly/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-28-4dc5a9dddc02>", line 2, in <module>
    from visual.graph import *

  File "/Users/johnhanly/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/visual.py", line 2
    def cli():/Users/johnhanly/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does line 2 of `/Users/johnhanly/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/visual.py` actually look like `def cli():/Users/johnhanly/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, or has something gone wrong in copying & pasting the error message?

Comment: Yes. Copied directly from IDE. I noticed the cli line too.

Comment: Well, that's clearly not right.  Unless you edited that file, something went very wrong during package installation.

Comment: I've tried other sample programs using visual module and all generate same error message.

Comment: Yes, because your copy of the visual module is broken.  I don't know how it got that way, but the general-purpose solution is to uninstall it and reinstall.

Comment: I just tried that. Now when I try installing visual with pip i get a message no module visual is found.  How do I install visual?  Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: I don't know what this "visual" package is, so I don't know.  How did you originally install it before?

Comment: I thought I installed it with pip but obviously not.  When I used pip to uninstall, it uninstalled some things and now my error message says no module visual is found.